# Query is taking lot of time how to resolve performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Query takes minimum 20 sec
I'm planing to create views
but if there are  sub query's we can't create view's

Please give some suggestions  on creating views

Any other suggestions are welcomed

```
SELECT 
    CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE) date,
    date_format(timecreated, '%d-%b-%Y'),
    SUM(t.enquiry_cnt) enquiry_cnt,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
        FROM
            mg_lead_suggested_listing
        WHERE
            CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
                AND source = 1) as lead_enquiry_cnt,
    SUM(t.suggested_cnt) suggested_cnt,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
        FROM
            mg_lead_suggested_listing
        WHERE
            CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
                AND source = 6) as lead_suggested_cnt,
    SUM(t.tot_cnt) tot_cnt,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
        FROM
            mg_lead_suggested_listing
        WHERE
            CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
                AND (source = 1 or source = 6)) AS lead_cnt,
    SUM(t.dropped_cnt) droped_cnt,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
        FROM
            mg_lead_suggested_listing
        WHERE
            CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
                AND (source = 1 || source = 6)
                && directory_status = 4) as lead_droped_cnt,
    sum(t.visit_pending_cnt) visit_pending_cnt,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id)
        FROM
            mg_lead_suggested_listing
        WHERE
            CAST(timecreated AS DATE) = CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
                AND (directory_status = 3 && finl_status = 6)) as lead_visit_pending_cnt
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CASE
                WHEN source = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END enquiry_cnt,
            CASE
                WHEN source = 6 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END suggested_cnt,
            CASE
                WHEN (source = 1 OR source = 6) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END tot_cnt,
            case
                when
                    ((source = 1 || source = 6)
                        && directory_status = 4)
                then
                    1
                else 0
            end dropped_cnt,
            case
                when (directory_status = 3 && finl_status = 6) then 1
                else 0
            end visit_pending_cnt,
            lead_id,
            timecreated
    FROM
        mg_lead_suggested_listing) AS t
group by CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
order by date desc
limit 10
```

FYI: there is no joins in this query
     I want to take count form only one table with some conditions

Comment: There might be a lot of things impacting query performance (indexes, number of records, joints, ...). This is almost impossible to put a finger on the root cause of your problem with so few informations...

Comment: @Bartdude: i feel this is causing becz of sub query 
im bit new to sql can you please let me know what info you want

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want using conditional aggregation.  The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE) as date, date_format(timecreated, '%d-%b-%Y'),
       SUM(t.enquiry_cnt) as enquiry_cnt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN source = 1 THEN lead_id END) as lead_enquiry_cnt,
       SUM(t.suggested_cnt) suggested_cnt,
       COUNT(DSTINCT CASE WHEN source = 6 THEN lead_id END) as lead_suggested_cnt,
       SUM(t.tot_cnt) as tot_cnt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN source IN (1, 6) THEN lead_id END) as lead_suggested_cnt,
       SUM(t.dropped_cnt) as droped_cnt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN source IN (1, 6) and Directory_status = 4 THEN lead_id END) as lead_droped_cnt,
       sum(t.visit_pending_cnt) visit_pending_cnt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Directory_status = 3 AND finl_status = 6 THEN lead_id END) as lead_visit_pending_cnt
FROM (SELECT (source = 1) as enquiry_cnt,
             (source = 6) as suggested_cnt,
             (source = 1 OR source = 6) as tot_cnt,
             (source IN (1, 6) AND directory_status = 4) as dropped_cnt,
             (directory_status = 3 AND finl_status = 6) as visit_pending_cnt,
            lead_id,
            timecreated
     FROM mg_lead_suggested_listing
    ) AS t
group by CAST(t.timecreated AS DATE)
order by date desc
limit 10;
```

Getting rid of the subquery and using a `where` clause on the date logic would probably also help.